# how to increase a variable which name You give

Tags: actionscript-3

how do i create a function where i put the name of the variable I want to make Math with,

what i mean is :
so somewhere in a enterFrameFunction i call **effectOne** and give its 1st parameter to be with the name of "myGravity"

```
private function effectOne(TriggeringVariable:String, minYposition:Number = 300, maxYposition:Number = 100):Number
{
     var myReturnVariable:Number = minYposition + maxYposition;

     TriggeringVariable +=10;
     if(TriggeringVariable > 980) TriggeringVariable = 980;
     if(TriggeringVariable > 500) minYposition = minYposition / 2;
     if(TriggeringVariable > 980) maxYposition = maxYposition / 2;

     return myReturnVariable;
}
```

but it gives me ->
**1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number.**

how do i make this ?

Comment: Although possible... this is a bad idea in almost all cases. By looking at your code I would say this is one of them. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Lets say i have 20 public variables.I`ll put the name of only one of them in the function, where (in that function )that variable will change its value

Comment: Again this sounds like a design issue. Passing strings is hard to maintain and not type safe. Looking at your example code, why cant you do: myvar = effectOne(myvar); instead of passing strings around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
this[triggeringVariable]+=10;
```

That will get the variable by the name you gave, so if `triggeringVariable` is "x", it will increase the `x` value of your instance.
But that will only work when that variable actually exists, and that cannot be checked at compile time. So if you make mistakes, you'll get runtime errors.